# Weblogic shows 500 error when there is no '/' at the end of the url

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, weblogic, broadleaf-commerce

I have a spring-based app (spring-security 3.2.9.RELEASE, spring-mvc 4.1.9.RELEASE), which is deployed to Weblogic 12.1.2.0.0

Here is the part from **weblogic.xml**

```
<wls:context-root>/admin</wls:context-root>
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So when I try the url `http://weblogicaddr:port/admin/` login page is opened correctly.

But for `http://weblogicaddr:port/admin`

I get the following error page

```
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: The path for getResource() must begin with a '/'
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.getResource(WebAppServletContext.java:755)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.util.PrecompressedArtifactFilter.useGzipCompression(PrecompressedArtifactFilter.java:152)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.util.PrecompressedArtifactFilter.doFilter(PrecompressedArtifactFilter.java:58)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.filter.BroadleafAdminRequestFilter$1.execute(BroadleafAdminRequestFilter.java:73)
    ... 71 more
```

I've tried changing in web.xml to `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`, but then got an error during deployment

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException:com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.ErrorMessagesException:null
```

So what changes in configuration should be made in order to get working url without ending '/'?

Comment: Try "/*" as your url-pattern.

Comment: @duffymo I've just added the result of it to the initial message.

Comment: Looks like it solved your problem and got you into the app.  No go figure out what dependency injection failed.  This is an entirely different problem.